# Validating response when using Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

I'm a complete newbie to Gatling.  I have a basic Post and Get working to a server and that is working fine.  What I want to do now is inspect the body of the payload being sent back to make sure it has what I'm expecting.  In particular, in one scenario, I am simply returning a string of 1000 "0" characters.  I'd like to check that all 100 characters came back.  I also plan to do a database lookup on a server that will return some data in JSON with a known response (let's call it "Fred").  I'd like to do a check that "Fred" is part of the response sent back.
I looked at assertions, but my understanding is that they are only used for the entire result set - such as checking that all responses were 200, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [checks](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0/http/http_check.html).

Then, you really should read the documentation, like the [quickstart](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0/quickstart.html) and the [advanced tutorial](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0/advanced_tutorial.html).